# jQuery Ajax form only submits after clicking twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit, preventdefault

I have a form which when submitted checks if Account Number is valid(through AJAX).

If invalid, it shows error message. This is working fine.

If valid, it should submit the form. It submits **but only after clicking Submit button twice**.

```
$('#account_validation_form').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var payers_account = $("input[name='payers_account']").val();

  $.post('ajax.php', {payers_account:payers_account}, function(data){

  if(data === 'invalid'){
     $(".account_invalid_message").html("<p>Given Account Number is invalid</p>");
  }

  else if(data === 'valid'){
     $("#account_validation_form").unbind('submit').submit()
  }

  });

});
```

I know something is wrong with calling `e.preventDefault()` there. But it is necessary and it can't be put inside AJAX Callback. So What would be the solution for this ?

Comment: hi, you can use else instead of else if(data === 'valid')

Comment: did you click and wait for some seconds to ensure that the `$.post` has finished?

Comment: Yes I waited for more than a Minute. Still didn't work in first click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#submit_button_id').on('click', function(e)
{
    var payers_account = $("input[name='payers_account']").val();
    $.post('ajax.php',
    {
        payment_amount: payment_amount,
        payers_account: payers_account,
    }, function(data)
    {
        if (data === 'invalid')
        {
            $(".account_invalid_message").html("<p>Given Account Number is invalid</p>");
        }
        else if (data === 'valid')
        {
            $("#account_validation_form").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

use this code and do a little change on HTML
change the type="submit" to type="button" for your submit button

Comment: please see my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707047/jquery-ajax-form-requires-2-clicks-to-submit

Answer (score 2):

Try binding the form post to submit button click event:
ie:

```
$('#submit_button_id').on('click', function(e){



    var payers_account = $("input[name='payers_account']").val();

  $.post('ajax.php', {payment_amount:payment_amount, payers_account:payers_account,}, function(data){

  if(data === 'invalid'){
     $(".account_invalid_message").html("<p>Given Account Number is invalid</p>");
  }

  else if(data === 'valid'){
     $("#account_validation_form").submit();
  }

  });

});
```

Comment: tried this . its not working. Its not submitting form even if data is valid.